# Geocoding android - Finding address based on coordinates

Tags: android, geocoding

I've put together this little function in my android app:

```
protected void toAddress(double lat, double lng, int maxResults) {

        String address = null;

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(TarsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, maxResults);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            address = addresses.get(0).getLocality().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ); 
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 

    }
```

The function call goes like this

```
 toAddress(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10);
```

But the app doesn't display any Toast with the address? I've debugged it and the correct address is in the addresses-list. As you can see I've tried to convert it to a string with the toString()-function. Anybody? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

You are not calling **.show()** after you create the Toast.